# ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword while executing the update query in shell script

Tags: oracle, shell

I am running a shellscript to update the database but getting the error **"ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword"**. But it works fine when executing the select query. I'm not getting what's the issue?

**Executing the script with select query:**

```
./dbScript.sh "select columnName from tableName where uniqueColumnName = 'XYZ'" <setEnvFilePath>
```

**Executing the script with update query:**

```
./dbScript.sh "UPDATE tableName SET columnName = columnName - interval '45' day WHERE uniqueColumnName = 'XYZ'" <setEnvFilePath>
```

**dbScript.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

function setEnvDetails()
{
  if [[ $JAVA_HOME = "" || $WL_HOME = "" ]]; then
            echo "Please set environment variables JAVA_HOME and WL_HOME."
            echo "Exiting..." && exit 1
    fi
    LOGIN_NM=${DB_USER_ROOT}/${DB_PASSWORD}@$DB
}

cd $2
. ./setEnv.sh

setEnvDetails

query=$1

#echo $query

sqlplus -s $LOGIN_NM  <<!
set echo off;
set feedback off;

set pagesize 0;
set trimspool off;

($query);
!
```

**setEnv.sh**

```
#!/bin/ksh

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Set user-defined variables.
# these values are taken from env_user.properties at installation time
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------


export JAVA_HOME=/nfs/tools/jdk/linux/jdk1.8.0_25-x64
if [ "${MEM_ARGS}" = "" ] ; then
   export MEM_ARGS="-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m - 
   XX:PermSize=512m -verbose:gc"
fi

export WL_HOME=/nfs/tools/bea/12.c/12.c/wlserver_12.1/

export DB_USER_ROOT=abcd11111
export DB_PASSWORD=abcd11111
export DB=sidev11g
export OM_DB_TYPE=ORACLE
export ORACLE_HOME=/nfs/tools/oracle/linux_64/11.2.0
export TNS_ADMIN=/nfs/tools/oracle/linux_64/11.2.0/network/admin
export THIN_URL=punvm-oracle03.sigmasys.net:1522:si12c

#export NLS_LANG=@nls.lang@

PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this line in **dbScript.sh**

```
($query);
```

You can only put parentheses around subqueries (which start with SELECT). [This is fine with SELECT](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF01702), but [is not valid with UPDATE](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10008.htm#SQLRF01708). Change it to this:

```
$query;
```